# How to echo only string from the image url?

Tags: php

How to extract the only name jenir and ellbull from the urls?with out numbers and extension
?

```
1330001337_jenir.jpg
1330001327_ellbull.png
```

// output

```
jenir
ellbull
```

Comment: You could regex the first set of numbers and underscore out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explode on _ or use an regular expression.

I prefer explode for such tasks.

```
$str = "1330001327_ellbull.png";
list($first,$second) = explode("_", $str);
echo $second;
```

Now you have ellbull.png.

If you want to loose the .png too, do the same for "." and use first part.

Answer (score 1):

```
$somevar = pathinfo(preg_replace('/^\d+_/', '', $file_name), PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Will do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/^\\d+_(\\w+)\\.[a-z]+$/", "1330001337_jenir.jpg", $match);
echo ($match[1]) // --> jenir
```

Comment: $img=$rowimg[image];
preg_match("^/\d+_(\w+)\.jpg$/", "$img", $match);
echo ($match[1])

Answer (score 0):

in your case use

```
$var = explode('_', $imageName);
echo $var[1];
```

UPD: 
if you do not need file extension, 
  then you use one more time `explode('.', $var[1])`
  or just `echo substr($var[1], -4)`
  or really use regExp to fetch only the name

Comment: Wouldn't this lead to "jenir.jpg"? An additional explode with "." would be needed, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = explode('_', $imgname);
$var = explode('.', $var[1]);
echo $var[0];
```

without regex.

Comment: if file name will have in it '.', then it will be a problem